# Python cx_Oracle.connect getting from code : ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: python, oracle, windows-10, amazon-rds

i try to do simple oracle connect to AWS RDS  from my windows 10

```
 connection = cx_Oracle.connect(           
               '{}/{}@{}/{}'.format( 'XXX',
                'XXXX',
                'XXX.rds.amazonaws.com',
                'orcl') ,
            encoding="UTF-8")
```

but i keep getting :

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

BUT when i connect from SQLPlus, everything is working ..
what Python driver needs to make it work ?

Comment: As [`cx_Oracle.connect`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.connect) documentation says: first argument is username, second argument is password, then - dsn in format of `<server>:<port>/<service_name>` (or composed with [`cx_Oracle.makedsn`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.makedsn)) or as the name of TNS entry. So it looks different from connection via SQLPlus

Comment: Actually that is that same order as SQL*Plus: username/password@connect_string.  And in fact you can use that same string as a the sole argument to `connect()`.

Comment: Review https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/ora-12545-12541-12514-01017/

Comment: the problem was the old oracle driver was in the path ( 11g ) which not good for connecting to RDS , i had to put new driver in the path